# Import table content from one database of one environment and write to other environment using XQUERY transformation in MARKLOGIC

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am being asked to work on a POC which is -

import data from one database from one environment and import the data to another environment using XQuery transformation in MarkLogic.

I am not sure if that can be possible as I understand that XQuery is basically used to transform any data within tables in same environment.
If the requirement is to import/export data to/from Marklogic , would not be the Marklogic Data Hub the only option? Or this can be achieved using XQuery too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options for exporting and importing data.

If there is a LOT of data, then [backup/restore](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/backup_restore), [flexible replication](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/flexrep/rep_intro), or [MLCP copy](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/copy) or [archive](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/export#id_93332) might be your best bet.

You can always move the data within an XQuery module. You can read the document (if executing on the source system, using `fn:doc()` or if pulling from a remote system, using the REST endpoints such as [`/v1/documents`](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/documents) or [`v1/search`](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/search)) and then insert with [`xdmp:document-insert()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-insert) or sending to `/v1/documents` using `xdmp:http-*` methods. If there are a ton of docs to move, you may want to orchestrate those actions with a batch tool, such as CoRB, and execute the XQuery module for each document in a separate transaction.